# Loop in Arduino LED circuit, with push-button for mode switching, stuck when moving to Mode 3

Tags: arduino, led, switches, pulldown

I have been working on an Arduino project: 4 LEDs connected on a breadboard, with series-parallel circuits, that are being controlled by push button. The desired behavior is to start in OFF mode, and upon button press to switch to each of the remaining 7 modes one after another, and then to loop around back to Mode 0 (OFF) after completing a full 8 mode loop.

There are 8 modes, including OFF, and I am using a 3-lead Keyes push button to switch through them, using switch statements and cases for each of the modes. The push button has a 10 kΩ resistor located between the middle and left (S) pin. I decided to use a pull-down resistor, and am using LOW as the initial buttonState variable.

5V is connected to the -, with S connected to pin 2 for control, and ground connected to the middle lead.

Here are my sources for that setup for the Keyes push-button:

https://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/modules/push-button/

https://startingelectronics.org/pinout/push-button/

Here is what happens when I upload the code to my Arduino:

1. It starts OFF as it's meant to
2. Push button, it switches to Mode 1, displays "Switching to mode 1"
3. Push button, it switches to Mode 2, displays "Switching to mode 2"
4. Push button, nothing happens, nothing is displayed, the program will not move forward

I have tried tons of different debug possibilities. The debounce logic you see commented out, I have tried both with and without and altered the debounce time, nothing changed.

I only saw a change once, and this is where it gets weird - if I put a print statement "Switching to Mode 3" right in the beginning of Mode 3's method, on the serial output I see "Switching to Mode 3", it switches to Mode 3, but it keeps displaying the text "Switching to Mode 3" over and over, and won't switch to Mode 4! Lastly, I have tested each mode separately and they all work fine.

Any ideas are welcome, I'm really stumped! Photos included, code found @ https://github.com/sw13tch-dio/Arduino_LEDproject

[image: breadboard setup]

[image: Arduino setup]

[image: whole project view]

Comment: Just to be sure, do you simply click the button, and nothing happens? Or did you keep it pushed for some time, how long?

Comment: What are the values of the resistors in serie with the diode ? I don't see well.

Comment: Note that the program on GitHub ... seems "incomplete" ...

Comment: @Antonio51 In which way, and is it relevant? It's an Arduino "program" which uses Arduino libraries and the user code is called by the Arduino libraries.

Comment: I don't know until now what is the "program" used ... and what I say is that the Github program does not even compile ...

Comment: @Antonio51 The program will compile, as long as it's uploaded and run in the Arduino IDE and run on an Arduino microprocessor board.

Comment: @Antonio51 the resistors are 220 with red and blue LED and 100 with green and yellow LED. I based these resistor numbers off a previous Stack post, where I was asking which resistors to use. Using these different resistors provided the proper level of illumination from all colors of the LEDs.

Comment: @Justme I actually never long pressed the button, it's worth a shot, I will try and get back to you thank you!

Comment: @DioB. See my answer. You need to press it at least up to 2 seconds because the MCU reads button once every 2 seconds!

Comment: please add the code to your question ... do not post links to code

Comment: @jsotola - My code was so lengthy, that adding it here seemed like the worse idea. Also, the formatting got janked up with only some of it showing as code snippets and the rest just poorly crowded into the space. Any suggestions to get around that problem? Is there some specific way of writing it that Stack's system likes best?

Comment: put three ``` on a blank line before the code and slso on a blank line after the code ... that will format it correctly

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is nothing wrong in the code.

Maybe you just expect it to work somehow differently and it does not work how you expect, and how you expect it to work should have been mentioned in the question.

Do realize that when you entered mode 2, you are spending there two seconds at a time each call, toggling LEDs and delaying, before returning so that the main loop code is again run and it can read the button.

So you need to keep the button pushed for until the code reads the button state, which can take up to 2 seconds.